# Как включить файл JavaScript в другой файл JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, include, импорт

Существует ли в JavaScript что-либо подобное `@import` в CSS, что позволяло бы включать файл JavaScript в другой файл JavaScript?

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/950087/564240)» [@Alec Smart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426996/).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В JavaScript нет операторов `import`, `include` или `require`. *(на самом деле, с 2015-го года есть в [модулях ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html))* Однако в JavaScript существуют другие способы включить внешний JavaScript-код.

#### Загрузка Ajax

С помощью Ajax вы можете загрузить дополнительный сценарий и затем воспользуйтесь `eval`. Это самый простой способ, но он пригоден только при работе на вашем собственном домене (причина – модель безопасности JavaScript sandbox security model). Использование `eval` также открывает двери перед «багами» и «хаками».

#### Загрузка jQuery

Библиотека [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) предоставляет возможность загрузки [одной строкой](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){
   alert("Сценарий загружен, но необязательно выполнен.");
});
```

#### Динамическая загрузка сценария

Добавьте тег script c URL сценария в HTML. Это идеальное решение для того чтобы избежать вычислительных затрат появляющихся при работе с jQuery. Сценарий может находиться на другом сервере.

Тег `<script>` можно вставить либо в раздел `<head>` веб-страницы, либо перед закрывающимся тегом `</body>`.

Оба эти решения обсуждались и иллюстрировались в статье *[Безумие JavaScript: загрузка динамических сценариев](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html)*.

### Определение момента завершения сценария

Теперь об одной серьёзной проблеме, связанной *с удалённой загрузкой кода*, о которой нельзя забывать. Современные веб-браузеры загружают файл и продолжают исполнение текущего сценария, так как они загружают всё асинхронно в целях повышения быстродействия (это справедливо как для jQuery, так и для ручного метода загрузки динамического сценария.)

Это значит, что если вы воспользуетесь подобными приёмами в чистом виде, *вы не сможете использовать только что загруженный код в строке, следующей за командой загрузки*, потому что он всё ещё будет «подгружаться».

Например: `my_lovely_script.js` содержит `MySuperObject`:

```
var js = document.createElement("script");
js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = jsFilePath;
document.body.appendChild(js);
var s = new MySuperObject();
```

> Error : MySuperObject is undefined

Затем вы обновляете страницу, нажав <kbd>F5</kbd>. И всё работает! Непонятно...

**Как же быть?**

Вы можете использовать небольшую хитрость (см. ссылку, которую я давал ранее). Вкратце: при загрузке сценария он использует заданное событие для запуска функции обратного вызова. Таким образом, вы можете поместить весь код, использующий удалённую библиотеку, в функцию обратного вызова. Например:

```
function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // Добавляем тег сценария в head – как и предлагалось выше
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Затем связываем событие и функцию обратного вызова.
    // Для поддержки большинства обозревателей используется несколько событий.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    // Начинаем загрузку
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

И затем код, который вы хотите использовать *после* загрузки сценария вы записываете в [лямбда-функцию](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function):

```
var myPrettyCode = function() {

    // А здесь делайте, что хотите
};
```

Запускаем то, что получилось:

```
loadScript("my_lovely_script.js", myPrettyCode);
```

Учтите, что сценарий может выполняться после или до загрузки DOM — в зависимости от браузера и от наличия в коде строки `script.async = false;`. Существует [великолепная общая статья по загрузке в Javascript](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/), в которой это рассматривается.

#### Объединение исходного кода

Ещё одно [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5511989/59087) – объединить два файла в один. Это можно сделать с минификацией, что позволит получить на выходе единый JavaScript-файл минимального размера, который будет делать всё нам необходимое.

<sub>Перевод ответа «[Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/564240)» [@e-satis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9951/).</sub>